# Issue passing 1 OR 2 query strings over URL in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm attempting to add some custom content to a page if i choose to add 1 or 2 variables over url. The issue is that my function ONLY works if both strings are passed, not if i only choose to use 1. I would like the option. The 2 strings being passed are 'rescompany' and 'locale'

re: `index.html?locale=someplace&rescompany=Google`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      function getUrlVars() {
        var vars = [],
          hash;
        var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
        for (var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++) {
          hash = hashes[i].split('=');
          vars.push(hash[0]);
          vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
        }
        return vars;
      }

      if (document.location.search.length) {
        var rescompany = getUrlVars()["rescompany"];
        var locale = getUrlVars()["locale"];

        if ((rescompany).length > 0) {
          $(".addtores").css('visibility', 'visible');
          $(".resname").append(decodeURIComponent(rescompany));
        }
        if ((locale).length > 0) {
          $(".introduction strong span").css('display', 'inline-block');
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I run your code, I get the following error message: `TypeError: rescompany is undefined` (check the error messages in your browser)

This means that your if test `(rescompany).length > 0` is wrong. This should be replaced with `rescompany !== undefined`.

So, your code should become something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  function getUrlVars() {
    var vars = [],
      hash;
    var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++) {
      hash = hashes[i].split('=');
      vars.push(hash[0]);
      vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
    }
    return vars;
  }

  if (document.location.search.length) {
    var vars = getUrlVars();
    var rescompany = vars["rescompany"];
    var locale = vars["locale"];

    if (rescompany !== undefined) {
      $(".addtores").css('visibility', 'visible');
      $(".resname").append(decodeURIComponent(rescompany));
    }
    if (locale !== undefined) {
      $(".introduction strong span").css('display', 'inline-block');
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: you nailed it- i missed that part of the logic. Thank you for the clarification!

Comment: Please always mark an answer as correct if it solved your problem. So, everyone knows the problem is solved.